# How to mock (??) a method called within a feature spec in Capybara/Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

All the guides to mocking (stubbing/whatever) in Rspec that I can find seem to be written for unit tests.

I have feature tests in Capybara/Rspec that look like this:

```
  visit page
  click button
  page should contain a png
```

This triggers actions in my controller that look like this:

```
  load parameters
  Worker.queue_a_lengthy_task_that_generates_a_png
  load page
```

I don't want to skip the lengthy task, but I don't want to run it either in the integration test. (I'll run it separately in a unit test.)

How can I ensure, in this example, that `Worker.queue_a_lengthy_task_that_generates_a_png` returns a Base64-encoding one-pixel PNG, so my integration tests don't take forever?

Sorry if this has been asked before but all the methods I have found seem to written for unit tests not feature specs.

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Comment: I've not had a need to trial Tiago's answer below but it looks encouraging